# How to count "actual" rows in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following columns in my dataset:

id | user_id | start_date | end_date | check_date

I want to get **check_date** from the first column, find all rows for which the **check_date** is between **start_date** and **end_date**. Then count the number of rows for every **user_id**. The same action for the second row and so on.

The point here is that I'll have amount of all actual rows for every user and every **check_date**.

This is my solution (in my data set I have less check dates than users):

```
df['actual_rows'] = 0
for c_d in df.check_date.unique():
  temp_df = df[(start_date <= c_d) & (end_date > c_d)]
  gr = temp_df.groupby('user_id')['id'].count()
  df.loc[df.check_date == c_d, 'actual_rows'] =\
                     df[df.check_date == c_d].user_id.map(gr.to_dict()) 
  del temp_df 
  del gr
```

I think it's kinda tricky and not very efficient. Maybe someone has a better solution?

Edit

Example rows:

```
id, user_id, start_date, end_date, check_date, actual
1, 1, 2018-11-05, 2018-12-06, 2018-11-22, 2
2, 1, 2018-11-10, 2018-11-25, 2018-11-24, 2
3, 1, 2018-12-05, 2018-12-31, 2018-12-20, 1
4, 1, 2018-12-25, 2019-01-30, 2018-12-30, 2
```

Comment: Please provide some example test data so we can reproduce your question.

Comment: Would you accept creating a dict with id and count of check_date values True as an answer? For example: {'id':[1,2,3,4],'dates_in_between':[10,23,13,42]}

Comment: @d_kennetz, edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# example data (with result column and spaces removed, a few rows added)   
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""id,user_id,start_date,end_date,check_date
1,1,2018-11-05,2018-12-06,2018-11-22
2,1,2018-11-10,2018-11-25,2018-11-24
3,1,2018-12-05,2018-12-31,2018-12-20
4,1,2018-12-25,2019-01-30,2018-12-30
5,2,2018-11-05,2018-12-06,2018-11-22
6,2,2018-11-10,2018-11-25,2018-11-24
"""))

def count_for_check_date(df, user_id, check_date):
    """
    :return: count of rows in df for given user_id and check_date
    """
    return df.query('user_id == @user_id and start_date <= @check_date and @check_date <= end_date').shape[0]

# apply the counting function to each pair of [user_id, checkdate] - assign result to column actual
df['actual'] = df[['user_id','check_date']].apply(lambda r: count_for_check_date(df, r[0], r[1]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   id  user_id  start_date    end_date  check_date  actual
0   1        1  2018-11-05  2018-12-06  2018-11-22       2
1   2        1  2018-11-10  2018-11-25  2018-11-24       2
2   3        1  2018-12-05  2018-12-31  2018-12-20       1
3   4        1  2018-12-25  2019-01-30  2018-12-30       2
4   5        2  2018-11-05  2018-12-06  2018-11-22       2
5   6        2  2018-11-10  2018-11-25  2018-11-24       2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not what I need. In the query you are checking that check_date is between start and end in the same row. I want to find all rows for which  check_date of current row is between start and end. "Actual" column is a result of this operation.

Comment: Edited to match your example & result